# Variational Autoencoder for Feature Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, probability, feature-extraction

I would like to ask if would it be possible (rather if it can make any sense) to use a variational autoencoder for feature extraction. I ask because for the encoding part we sample from a distribution, and then it means that the same sample can have a different encoding (Due to the stochastic nature in the sampling process). Thanks!

Comment: A couple of useful references on variational auto-encoders:  http://kvfrans.com/variational-autoencoders-explained/ and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908v2.pdf  (23-page tutorial on VAEs)

Comment: Thanks! I liked the comparison with GANs

Answer (score 0):

Yes the feature extraction goal is the same for vae's or sparse autoencoders.
Once you have an encoder plug-in a classifier on the extracted features.

Best reggards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes the output of encoder network can be used as your feature.

Just think about this: using the output of encoder network as input, the decoder network can generate you an image quite like your old image. Therefore the output of encoder network has pretty much covered most of the information in your original image. In other words, they are the most important features of your original image that distinguish it from other images.

The only thing you want to pay attention to is that variational autoencoder is a stochastic feature extractor, while usually the feature extractor is deterministic. You can either use the mean and variance as your extracted feature, or use Monte Carlo method by drawing from the Gaussian distribution defined by the mean and variance as "sampled extracted features".

Comment: hi. I'd like to ask if you tried to use the mean as the feature. if so, how is the performance.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can.
I used the below code to extract the important features from my dataset.

```
prostate_df <- read.csv('your_data')

prostate_df <- prostate_df[,-1] # first column.

train_df<-prostate_df

outcome_name <- 'subtype' # my label column

feature_names <- setdiff(names(prostate_df), outcome_name)


library(h2o)

localH2O = h2o.init()

prostate.hex<-as.h2o(train_df, destination_frame="train.hex")


prostate.dl = h2o.deeplearning(x = feature_names,
                                #y="subtype",
                                training_frame = prostate.hex,
                                model_id = "AE100",
                                # input_dropout_ratio = 0.3,  #Quite high,
                                #l2 = 1e-5,  #Quite high
                                autoencoder = TRUE,
                                #validation_frame = prostate.hex,
                                #reproducible = T,seed=1,
                                hidden = c(1), epochs = 700,
                                #activation = "Tanh",
                               #activation ="TanhWithDropout",
                                 activation ="Rectifier",
                               #activation ="RectifierWithDropout",
                                standardize = TRUE,
                               #regression_stop = -1,
                               #stopping_metric="MSE",
                                train_samples_per_iteration = 0,
                                variable_importances=TRUE
)


label1<-ncol(train_df)

train_supervised_features2 = h2o.deepfeatures(prostate.dl, prostate.hex, layer=1)

plotdata = as.data.frame(train_supervised_features2)

plotdata$label = as.character(as.vector(train_df[,label1]))


library(ggplot2)

qplot(DF.L1.C1, DF.L1.C2, data = plotdata, color = label, main = "Cancer Normal  Pathway data ")



prostate.anon = h2o.anomaly(prostate.dl, prostate.hex, per_feature=FALSE)
head(prostate.anon)

err <- as.data.frame(prostate.anon)


h2o.scoreHistory(prostate.dl)

head(h2o.varimp(prostate.dl),10)

h2o.varimp_plot(prostate.dl)
```

Comment: I double-checked and H2O does not support *variational* auto-encoders; the code shown here is for just a normal auto-encoder.